# Azure DevOps: Restrict pull requests to subset of team

Tags: git, azure-devops, pull-request

Suppose I have a team with 10 developers, but I want all pull requests to be completed by a senior developer of which I have 2 on my team. In my branch policy I can automatically add teams, individual users, and groups as reviewers.

Teams - As mentioned I don't want the whole team to be able to approve the review.

Individuals - I don't want to add individual senior devs to the policy because if those 
Sr Devs change role, move to a different team, etc I have to go update all the policies.

Groups - Would be ideal, but there's a caveat. Pull requests assigned to groups don't 
show as assigned to the user when reviewing "My pull requests". PRs only show if assigned
to an individual or a team.

Broken? Working as designed? Future functionality?

Comment: What exactly are you asking here? *Broken? Working as designed? Future functionality?* doesn't make a lot of sense

Comment: What your describing here sounds a [lot like forks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/forks?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can define reviews in the branch policy. does it not accept group as a reviewer?

Comment: It does accept groups. When I then go look at my pull requests that pull request doesn't show. You have to go to the repository and then look for the active pull requests. The my pull requests feature will show you pull requests assigned to you or teams you are in in any project for the entire organization which is much more convenient.

Comment: Liam I'm asking if Groups not showing up in the My Pull Requests feed is broken, WAD, or future. It works for teams. Pull request feed can be found at "https://<account>.visualstudio.com/_pulls"

Comment: I think this is by design. You may know that if the user in the group getting assigned by default makes a comment or casts a vote (approve, reject, etc) they will then be added to the pull request and the PR will show up in their profile and dashboard PR widgets that are using the "assigned to me" option. If you want to have a dashboard that shows PRs for those users, you should create a **PR Approvers** team (requires addl. settings to trim the boards, b/c teams get boards by default) and use the "Assigned to Team" option on the widget. BTW that team needs to be opted in for notifications too

Comment: Another option for a "dashboard" functionality to view pull requests is the [Pull Request Dashboard](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryanstedman.tfs-pullrequest-dashboard&targetId=e96b5f9a-fd37-48e4-9862-8cf9857f02e9&utm_source=vstsproduct&utm_medium=ExtHubManageList) extension.

Comment: Amending my first comment, if you use groups instead of teams, those users won't get emails to notify them that they are on a pull request because of their membership.

Comment: Thanks Josh. We are using the SaaS version, not on-prem so the extension will not show us PRs by indirect team membership according to their description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I've managed this in the past is to have two teams:

**Developers:**

- Matt
- Mark
- Bill
- [project]\Senior Developers

**Senior Developers:**

- Sue
- Pam

Most privileges you define on Developers.  Additional privileges like PR permsissions you assign to Senior Developers.

One could also add the **Senior Developers** team as "required" on the branch policy, and keep the **Developers** team rights to pull requests, allowing other devs to still approve requests and comment etc. but the request can't be completed until a senior dev approves it.

Comment: One could also add the **Senior Developers** team as "required" on the branch policy, and keep the **Developers** team rights to pull requests, allowing other devs to still approve requests and comment etc. but the request can't be completed until a senior dev approves it.

Comment: I like that idea the best Josh. I wasn't a big fan of having 2 teams with their own areas that I can't remove. Groups should be for encapsulating permissions into roles. If you want to submit that answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I updated my answer to include his comment.  What @JoshGust was recommending was actually along the lines of what I meant.  I don't think you have to create an area when you create a team.  There should be a checkbox that you can deselect.

Comment: Good point on unchecking the default area. I was looking at a pre-existing team for reference and the option was grayed out, but I was not on the correct page to delete the Team. Specifically I like that Josh suggested using a Group for the Senior Devs showing they are still part of the team, but have elevated permissions due to group membership.

Comment: @Matt is correct. Not creating a team area by default will give the "configuration required" page if one is trying to navigate to the board for that team.